# Assign value if another value is contained in a list (power bi, dax)

Tags: if-statement, powerbi, dax

I imported a table into Power BI that looks as follows:

```
  id  value
  01    123
  02    456
  03    789
  04    999
```

I want to declare a new column called `KIND` using an `IF` statement. Something along the lines of:

`KIND = if(id is in ("01", "02", "22", "89"), "baker", "other")`.

The desired result looks as follows:

```
  id  value   KIND
  01    123  baker
  02    456  baker
  03    789  other
  04    999  other
```

Comment: if(id in {"01", "02", "22", "89"}, "baker", "other")

Comment: It worked. Would you like to post that as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just so there's an answer not just in the comments:

```
KIND := IF ( TableName[id] IN {"01", "02", "22", "89"}, "baker", "other" )
```

Note that the `IN` function won't work in some older versions of Excel and you'll have to use `CONTAINSROW` instead.

```
KIND := IF ( CONTAINSROW ( {"01", "02", "22", "89"}, TableName[id] ), "baker", "other" )
```

Comment: I was waiting for someone to post the answer in the comments as an answer to the question, haha.
Either way, why are you using `:=` and what does Excel's backwards compatibility have to do with this?

Comment: The : is optional but sometimes used to distinguish calculated columns from measures. DAX is used in Excel Power Pivot too so I also provided a version that doesn't depend on the newer syntax.